# Glitchy display screen

Tags: verilog, vga

I am trying to display a picture on my monitor using FPGA board. When I send my signal, everything is alright and the monitor receives signal but the picture area is glitchy with white stripes and black Stripes. As I am trying to display on 640x480 resolution, I used clock divider to divide the on board 50 MHz clock to 25 MHz with the following code block

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
      clkout=~clkout;
end
```

I then send this processed output clock to my VGA monitor and the bram to do the functions. Is it the main cause of my VGA monitor not displaying the picture correctly?
Do I have to use PLL to generate the output clock?
Edit: I tried out assigning the final output as registers but still getting the glitchy screen. I am attaching the block code of the VGA controller here

```
    module vga_pl(clk,clkout,blankn,syncn,redf,bluef,greenf,h_sync,v_sync,zb,zg,zr);
input clk;
output wire clkout;
reg [7:0]red,blue,green;
output [7:0]redf,bluef,greenf;
output reg h_sync,v_sync;
output reg blankn,syncn;
reg [9:0]hs=10'b 0000000000;
reg [9:0]vs=10'b 0000000000;
reg hvidon,vvidon;
wire [23:0]outbus;
PLL25MHZ m_PLL(
               .clk_clk(clk),
                    .clkout_clk(clkout)
                    );              
reg [12:0]addr_cnt=0;
output [1:0]zb=0;
output [1:0]zr=0;
output [1:0]zg=0;
bram_pl m_br(
          .clk(clkout),
           .we(1'b 0),
           .addr(addr_cnt[12:0]),
           .inbus(24'b 000000000000000000000000),
           .outbus(outbus));
always @(posedge clkout)begin
    if(hs==799)begin
           hs<=0;
            if(vs==525)vs<=0;
            else vs<=vs+1;
            end
    else hs<=hs+1;
     if((hs>=0)&&(hs<=95))h_sync<=0;
     else h_sync<=1;
     if((vs>=0)&&(vs<=1))v_sync<=0;
     else v_sync<=1;
     if(((hs>=0)&&(hs<=143))||((hs>=784)&&(hs<=799)))begin
            red<=8'b 00000000;
            green<=8'b 00000000;
            blue<=8'b 00000000;
            blankn<=1'b 0;  
            syncn<=1'b 0;
            hvidon<=0;              
            end             
    else hvidon<=1;
    if(((vs>=0)&&(vs<=34))||((vs>=515)&&(vs<=524)))begin
                 red<=8'b 00000000;
                 green<=8'b 00000000;
                 blue<=8'b 00000000;                                  
                 blankn<=1'b 0;  
                 syncn<=1'b 0;
                 vvidon<=0;                   
                end
   else vvidon<=1;
    if((hvidon)&&(vvidon))begin
             if((hs>=383 && hs<=463)&&(vs>=274 && vs<=353))begin
                             red<=outbus[7:0];
                             green<=outbus[15:8];
                             blue<=outbus[23:16];
                                      addr_cnt<=addr_cnt+1;
                             end
                else begin
                             red<=8'b 00000000;
                             green<=8'b 00000000;
                             blue<=8'b 000000000;
                                 end
                blankn<=1'b 1;
                syncn<=1'b 0;
                end

end
assign redf=red;
assign bluef=blue;
assign greenf=green;
endmodule
```

This is my Bram code

```
module bram_pl(clk,inbus,outbus,addr,we);
parameter DATAFILE="test80.hex";
parameter RAM_WIDTH =24;
parameter RAM_ADDR_BITS=13;
parameter INIT_START_ADDR= 0;
parameter INIT_END_ADDR=6399;
input clk,we;
input [RAM_WIDTH-1:0]inbus;
output reg [RAM_WIDTH-1:0]outbus;
input [RAM_ADDR_BITS-1:0]addr;
(* ramstyle = "M4K" *)reg[RAM_WIDTH-1:0]mem[0:6399];
initial begin
      $readmemh(DATAFILE,mem, INIT_START_ADDR, INIT_END_ADDR);
        end

always @(posedge clk)begin
         if (we)begin
            mem[addr] <=inbus;
                end
         outbus<=mem[addr];
end
endmodule
```

This is the image that I am trying to display.[image]

This is the condition of the screen after trying to display [image: Glitchy display screen]

If I try to do it with Flag of benin, this is the output[image: flagofbeninglitchy]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144429/discussion-on-question-by-tahmid-mahbub-170021040-glitchy-display-screen); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was improper addressing of the VGA display frame where I didn't reset the address count to zero before each frame. Setting the address to zero before each frame gave the desired image output